# How to insert many-to-many entities without having tracking issues (already being tracked)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following models/tables:

```
CV:
   int ID
   string Title
   List<SkillCV> SkillsCVs // many-to-many junction/associative model/table to link the 2 tables

SkillCV:
   int CvID
   int SkillID
   bool IsCore

Skill:
   int ID
   string Title
```

Then I have the following method:

```
public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(CV cv, List<SkillsCVs> skillsCVs)
{
   var cvDB = await context.Set<CV>()
               .Include(CV => CV.SkillsCVs)
                  .ThenInclude(skillCV => skillCV.Skill)
               .Include(CV => CV.User)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(CV => CV.Id == cv.Id);
   cvDB.Title = cv.Title;
   cvDB.SkillsCVs.Clear();
   cvDB.SkillsCVs.AddRange(skillsCVs);
   context.Set<CV>().Update(cvDB); // EXCEPTION
   return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The problem is that I have CVSkill entity with CV id 8, Skill id 1, so the composite key is (1, 8). Then I use this method to add (1, 14) - the same skill with ID 1 to CV with ID 14 and it says that CV with id 8 is already being tracked or that the (1, 8) can't be duplicated. I suppose that Skill 1 is still tracked to CV 8, because I join CV -> SkillCV -> Skill. How can I update the CV with ID 14 to insert (1, 14) into its SkillsCVs collection, without having tracking/duplicating issues? I suppose that it's not a problem to have both (1, 8) and (1, 14) entities, because the composite keys as a whole are unique even though the Skill IDs are the same?

---

EDIT:
Now I have the following code:

```
public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(CV cv, List<SkillsCVs> skillsCVs)
{
   var cvDB = await context.Set<CV>()
               .AsNoTracking()
               .Include(CV => CV.SkillsCVs)
                  .ThenInclude(skillCV => skillCV.Skill)
               .Include(CV => CV.User)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(CV => CV.Id == cv.Id);
   cvDB.Title = cv.Title;

   foreach (var skillCV in cvDB.SkillsCVs)
      context.Entry(skillCV).State = EntityState.Detached;

   cvDB.SkillsCVs.Clear();

   foreach (var skillCV in skillsCVs)
      cvDB.SkillsCVs.Add(skillCV);

   context.Set<CV>().Update(cvDB); // EXCEPTION
   return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

When I try to add a single entity skillCV (skillsCVs collection with 1 entity) it throws: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.`

When I try to add a bunch of entities through the skillsCVs in CV with **ID 14** it throws: `System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'CV' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 8}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`AsNoTracking()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) like `await context.Set<CV>().AsNoTracking()`, It should not throw exception as it won't be track entities anymore.

```
public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(CV cv, List<SkillsCVs> skillsCVs)
{
   var cvDB = await context.Set<CV>()
               .AsNoTracking()
               .Include(CV => CV.SkillsCVs)
                  .ThenInclude(skillCV => skillCV.Skill)
               .Include(CV => CV.User)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(CV => CV.Id == cv.Id);
   cvDB.Title = cv.Title;
   cvDB.SkillsCVs.Clear();
   cvDB.SkillsCVs.AddRange(skillsCVs);
   context.Set<CV>().Update(cvDB); // EXCEPTION
   return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

---

**Edit 1** Or your `cvDB` is already being `track`, so try with removing `context.Set<CV>().Update(cvDB);`. It will explicitly `track` the `entity` so it might be causing the issue.

```
public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(CV cv, List<SkillsCVs> skillsCVs)
{
   var cvDB = await context.Set<CV>()
               .Include(CV => CV.SkillsCVs)
                  .ThenInclude(skillCV => skillCV.Skill)
               .Include(CV => CV.User)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(CV => CV.Id == cv.Id);
   cvDB.Title = cv.Title;
   cvDB.SkillsCVs.Clear();
   cvDB.SkillsCVs.AddRange(skillsCVs);
   // context.Set<CV>().Update(cvDB); // comment this line
   return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

---

**Edit 2** Did not use `AsNoTracking()` here. Updated code to get existing SkillsCVs, then clear `cvDB.SkillsCVs`and while adding new SkillsCV check if the same is already exists or not. If exists then mark existing one as Detached & newly added as Modified. Also comment line `context.Set<CV>().Update(cvDB);`.

```
public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(CV cv, List<SkillsCVs> skillsCVs)
{
    var cvDB = await context.Set<CV>()
                .Include(CV => CV.SkillsCVs)
                    .ThenInclude(skillCV => skillCV.Skill)
                .Include(CV => CV.User)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(CV => CV.Id == cv.Id);
    cvDB.Title = cv.Title;
   
    // Retrieve list of existingSkillsCVs so later we can mark it as Detached and newly added skillCV as Modified.
    var existingSkillsCVs = cvDB.SkillsCVs.ToList();
   
    cvDB.SkillsCVs.Clear();
   
    foreach(var skillsCV in skillsCVs)
    {
        cvDB.SkillsCVs.Add(skillsCV);
        
        // Find SkillsCV if already exists. If exists then Detach it & set newly added skillsCV as Modified.
        var existingSkillsCV = existingSkillsCVs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CvID == skillsCV.CvID && x.SkillID == skillsCV.SkillID);
        if (existingSkillsCV != null)
        {
            context.Entry(existingSkillsCV).State = EntityState.Detached;
            context.Entry(existingSkillsCV.Skill).State = EntityState.Detached;
            context.Entry(skillsCV).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }       
    }
    
    // context.Set<CV>().Update(cvDB); // comment this line
    return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: It actually generated the right SQL query (I'm logging the EF queries to see the SQL as well). BUT... `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.`

Comment: When I remove the .AsNoTracking() and the Update it says: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SkillsCVs'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SkillsCVs'. The duplicate key value is (1, 8).` when it tries to insert key (1, 14), which is not a duplicate of (1, 8). IDK why this is happening.

Comment: I have 1 question. Will the cvDB.SkillsCVs.ToList() work? It creates a copy of the collection and I'm not sure if the Entry(copiedExistingSkillsCVs) will work. I will try it in 3-4 hours and I will tell you the result (probably will make your answer as a solution, because you've already made a tremendous effort and if it does not work, it's probably a problem in my code). I just want to know if the .ToList() copying (not getting the same references) would be a problem.

Comment: No, it will be copied with reference. Only thing I am concerned is that I am not sure whether it will remove `existing SkillsCVs` which are not in `skillsCVs`. And you shouldn't mark answer as `accepted` unless it work because later if other users has same issue and try this solution it won't work for them and they'll be confused.

Comment: When I Add skill with ID 1 to CV with ID 14 it says `System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'CV' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 8}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.` And I don't understand why this happens. Yes, the skill 1 is referenced to CV 8, but why creating new entity (1,14) should be a problem for (1,8). I tried to use AsNoTracking for EVERY method in my repository and this exception still persists.

Comment: Try adding `context.Entry(existingSkillsCV.Skill).State = EntityState.Detached;`, updated in answer also.

Comment: Yes, I made the changes you mentioned in the EDIT. It still doesn't work. Also when I remove an added skill it throws exception that it's already being tracked on the entity. It only lets me to add only 1 skill per request and this skill must not be referenced in a composite key with another CV.

Comment: I don't have any further suggestions, you can try different things and if it worked posted it as an answer. It might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Detach` to detach current CVSkills
like :

```
  var cvDB = await context.Set<CV>()
               .AsNoTracking()
               .Include(CV => CV.SkillsCVs)
                  .ThenInclude(skillCV => skillCV.Skill)
               .Include(CV => CV.User)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(CV => CV.Id == cv.Id);
   cvDB.Title = cv.Title;
   foreach( var skillsCV in cvDB.SkillsCVs)
   {
      context.Entry(skillsCV).State = EntityState.Detached;
   }
   cvDB.SkillsCVs.Clear();
   cvDB.SkillsCVs.AddRange(skillsCVs);
   context.Set<CV>().Update(cvDB); // EXCEPTION
   return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Your `foreach` loop should be before `cvDB.SkillsCVs.Clear();`.

Comment: I don't have a Detach method to the DbContext. I made a quick research and I saw that this is a method of the ObjectContext. I haven't worked with the ObjectContext yet. Can you tell me how to access it through the dbcontext or is it not possible?

Comment: Can I use Context.Entry(cv.SkillsCVs).State = EntityState.Detached; instead of new ObjectContext().Detach(...

Comment: @akurasu When I use Context.Entry(cv.SkillsCVs) to change their State to Detached it says: `System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'HashSet<SkillCV>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.`

Comment: I have `edit` the answer, you need `foreach` loop before `cvDB.SkillsCVs.Clear();`. Also don't use `DbSet` `cv.SkillsCVs` but use single entity as `skillsCV`.

Comment: @Karan It generates the update/insert query, and it seems that it would work perfectly and then........ `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.`

Comment: @Karan Can you check my EDIT? Let me know if you have anything left to mention. Meanwhile I will give you a like. I really appreciate your effort and I'm so bummed about this tracker :(